# JQuery attribute that turns off the As Of subtitle on the analytics:reportChart components

Tags: visualforce, jquery

My 'AS Of' report chart subtitles are showing again. Not sure when but everything seems to be in order. Does anyone know if this command is deprecated ?

```
<apex:page standardController="Audit__c"  showHeader="false" >
<apex:variable var="audit" value="{!Audit__c}" /> 

<!-- JQuery attribute that turns off the As Of subtitle on the analytics:reportChart components -->
<style>
.asOfDate{display:none!important;}
</style>

......

    <apex:panelGrid columns="3" id="Grid1">    
            <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O16000007LVFN" size="tiny" showRefreshButton="false" cacheResults="true" filter="[{column:'Audit__c.Name',operator:'equals',value:'{!Audit__c.Name}'}]" rendered="{!audit.Chart_Vehicle_Model_Year__c}" />
            <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O16000007LVFJ" size="tiny" showRefreshButton="false" cacheResults="true" filter="[{column:'Audit__c.Name',operator:'equals',value:'{!Audit__c.Name}'}]" rendered="{!audit.Chart_Rating_Tier__c}" />
            <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O16000007LVFE" size="tiny" showRefreshButton="false" cacheResults="true"  filter="[{column:'Audit__c.Name',operator:'equals',value:'{!Audit__c.Name}'}]" rendered="{!audit.Chart_Credit_Score__c}" /> 
        </apex:panelGrid>
```

Comment: That looks like CSS. Use your browser’s “Inspect” to look at the element you want to hide and figure out a CSS selector that matches.

Comment: Yes, the css attribute is display:none. But this has been working for years. I don't see any difference via inspection.

Comment: So there is still a class name of asOfDate on the element? Element nesting and class names can change as they are not considered part of a fixed API.

Comment: looks like, if I am interpreting correctly, it is now .analyticsEmbeddedChart .hideLoading {display: none;}

Comment: subtitle still shows even when changing to <style>.hideloading{display:none;}</style>

Comment: Resolved in answer below and code. @KeithC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved by adding !important to the CSS to ensure rule is always applied. Code updated above.